# What causes a PHP file to actually run?

Tags: php, silex

I need my index file to point to another index file.  In this case index.php points to index-1.php.  The problem I'm facing is the PHP in index-1.php is not running.  I've tried 2 ways in my index.php file to access index-1.php

```
// way 1
require_once __DIR__ . "/web/source/index-1.php";
```

and I've tried a framework (silex ) ( setup code is omitted but it works fine ).

```
// way 2
$app->get('/{name}', function($name) use($app) {
    return $app->sendFile(__DIR__ . '/web/source/index-1.php');
});
```

In each case the raw file is sent to the client with out the php being interpreted.

How do I make the PHP file actually run?

I've verified the basic things, such as the file paths being set correctly and the file actually being sent.

Comment: Do you have PHP installed on your FTP? PHP.ini set up properly? Are you using the correct file path?

Comment: I've already narrowed the problem down to the PHP not being interpreted in the index-1.php file.  index.php is being interpreted and the paths are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requiring or including is a valid way to have php code run.  There is an error in this code path if your code is not running.

You need to post more code.

`SendFile()` is not a valid way to have code run as it only sends a file.